# How to write nunit test case for singleton class

Tags: class, testing, singleton, nunit, case

NAudioEngine is a singleton class how to write the can execute in the following code snippet:

```
    private bool CanAddNew(object parameter)
    {
        if (NAudioEngine.Instance.SelectionEnd.Milliseconds != 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
   [Test]
    public void AddNewCommandMainVMTestTrue()
    {
        MainVm mainVM = new MainVm();
        RelayCommand command = (RelayCommand)mainVM.AddNewCommand;
        bool canAddNew = command.CanExecute(null);
        Assert.IsTrue(canAddNew);

    }
```

Comment: Pass the singleton value as the parameter. Accessing static/singleton values with the method make it difficult to test in isolation as it is coupled to something you may not be able to change for the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   [Test]
    public void AddNewCommandMainVMTest()
    {
        NAudioEngine.Instance.OpenFile(WAV_FILE);
        NAudioEngine.Instance.SelectionBegin = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
        NAudioEngine.Instance.SelectionEnd = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
        MainVm mainVM = new MainVm();
        RelayCommand command = (RelayCommand)mainVM.AddNewCommand;
        bool canAddNew = command.CanExecute(mainVM);
        Assert.IsFalse(canAddNew);
    }
```